# Random UDP message received needs to be parsed to python file through rsyslog omprog

Tags: python, logging, rsyslog

I'm setting up a python script that will parse the inputs received via UDP from another server. Since the message or number of messages can be received randomly, I'm trying to rsyslog omprog to parse the inputs. However, I'm unable to read the message on UDP and unable to send the input received as parameter to python using omprog

Receiving syslog message from particular server will be stored in /var/log/pcrf_notification.log Therefore, I configured the rsyslog.conf like below:

```
         [root@PORSG1NT101A]# vi /etc/rsyslog.conf
         $ModLoad imudp
         $UDPServerRun 514

         $template RemoteLogs,"/var/log/%HOSTNAME%/pcrf_notification.log"
         *.* ?RemoteLogs
```

The content withing the pcrf_notification.log will be:

```
 Mar 15 16:27:30 PORPF0MP1 Policy Syslog: 5540149665,123,5000001,2019-03-15T16:27:30.290

 Mar 15 16:27:52 PORPF0MP1 Policy Syslog: 5540149665,123,5000001,2019-03-15T16:27:52.895
```

Now i need to send each line when received to a python script. This is I'm failing at.

For example, I need to send

```
 "Mar 15 16:27:52 PORPF0MP1 Policy Syslog: 5540149665,123,5000001,2019-03-15T16:27:52.895"
```

to a python script.

I created a pcrf_scripting.conf file in rsyslog.d folder

```
 [root@PORSG1NT101A rsyslog.d]# vi /etc/rsyslog.d/pcrf_scripting.conf
                   $ModLoad omprog
                  :inputname, isequal, "imudp" action(type="omprog"
                   binary="/tmp/hello.py --param1 a --param2 b"
                   template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat")
```

I need to replace --param1 a --param2 b with each line.

Comment: omprog is not intended to run a different command for every input message. Normally, it runs a program then sends each message to the standard input of that program.

Comment: Yes @meuh. That is what I'm trying to achieve. To send each message to the input of that program (in my case python script). Could you help me out here

Comment: Perhaps you are not including the second conf file? Make sure you have the line `$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf` in file `/etc/rsyslog.conf`. Otherwise your conf seems ok. You must make your `hello.py` do something like `sys.stdin.readline()` to get each line.

Comment: So could I use in my pcrf.conf file in rsyslog.d/ folder

  module(load="omprog")

  action(type="omprog"
     binary="/tmp/hello.py %msg%
     template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat")

Comment: I dont know if that would work, but your `hello.py` would have to exit after every message, which would be very ineffecient. I've posted an answer where the program is started once and runs forever, reading stdin.

Answer (score 0):

This minimal example worked for me (rsyslogd version 8.30.0). In `/etc/rsyslog.conf` we have

```
$ModLoad imudp # UDP listener
$UDPServerRun 514
$ModLoad omprog
:inputname, isequal, "imudp"  action(type="omprog"
  binary="/tmp/prog.py" template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat")
```

In `/tmp/prog.py` we have

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
with open("/tmp/output","w",encoding='utf8',errors='ignore') as fd:
    for data in sys.stdin:
        print("got data: %s" % data[:-1], file=fd, flush=True)
```

When a udp packet arrives it is passed through to the python program which prints it to file `/tmp/output`. Make sure to `chmod a+rx /tmp/prog.py`.