# How can I receive syslog messages in a Python 3.6 program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syslog

I did a quick Google search and saw a few Python modules for sending syslog messages.

How can I receive syslog messages in a Python program? Does the Python 3.6 standard library have something that I'm not aware of that does this?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/marcelom/4218010 This might give you a hint.

Comment: If you are already running rsyslogd then check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55831686/5008284) showing how to get it, for example, to send received udp traffic to a python program.

Answer (score 4):

By default rsyslog uses UDP. Python standard lib has a [UDP Server example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.UDPServer). I went even more bare bones.

```
import socketserver

class MyUDPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print(self.request[0])

with socketserver.UDPServer(('10.0.1.90', 9999), MyUDPHandler) as server:
    server.serve_forever()
```

Triggering a rsyslog message on my test device resulted in:

```
b'<174>Oct 15 13:59:08 CN-6-12 Event: Logged into console: admin'
```

Served my purposes for testing the syslog functionality of my test device.

Answer (score 1):

Syslog messages are supposed to be received by the syslog daemon. You couldn't find python modules for receiving syslog messages because usually there is no need for a python program to receive syslog messages. There is usually only one syslog daemon receiving syslog messages per machine.

Maybe you should look for this instead: [Logging module for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)? It is not a replacement for syslog, but it is more appropriate choice for logging in 99% of python programs.

Comment: Thanks. I actually do have a need for a python program to receive syslog messages - I have network devices sending syslog to a management system and I want to program in some kind of logic to send out an Android push notification using an AWS service. Is a better alternative to have the syslog daemon write to a file? But then how would a write to the file notify the Python program? I'd like to avoid polling to detect a file write if possible.